# Xpath Wildcard (for example: "/Data/Customers/D*")

Tags: c#, xpath, wildcard

I am selecting some nodes using XPath, and would like to use wildcards. Is this possible?

Something like the following would be useful:

```
foreach (XmlNode xml_node in xml_document.SelectNodes("/Data/Customers/D*"))
{
   //
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
/Data/Customers/*[starts-with(name(.), "D")]
```